# ROR: Dynamically generate URL for 'new' action based on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slug, friendly-id

I have the following task:

1. There are categories of events.
2. I create an event only with passing a category id to the 'new' action of events.
3. I need to hide the URL of 'new' action (which is like /event?category_id=1) behind a slug, which is based on a category name. Like this  /large_event , /small_event. This means that passing an id of Large events category should show the user 'new' form of an event with /large_event URL

I have tried to do this using friendly id gem. May be Iam missing something, but it allows to make a slug for a model. But I need to make a slug only for 'new' action for one model based on the attribute of another model.

The number of categories can vary - hard coding is not an option. Is there any graceful way to do this?

Comment: have a look at the docs for routing http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @KcUS_unico , I have found one way - slug the category and make the event a nested resource. I will allow me to have URLs like /small_category/events/new. But I`ll need to rewrite already tested code. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have used two things to implement this:
1. Friendly ID gem to generate slugs for the Categories and generate URLs like the following for the users to have access to the "new" action.
2. Rails route constraints with regexp. It looks like

```
 get "arenda/:category_slug" => 'auctions#new', constraints: { category_slug: /\w+/ }
```

And to finish it up - I have created a proper controller to filter out inconsistent params and search by slug.